# Outputting the correct letter grade based on the grades being inputted in

Tags: c++

Every time I input three grades into the program, it comes out with the correct percentage number, but not the correct letter grade. For example, if I put in my three grades each as 100, it will output: Your average is 100, your letter grade is F. How do I fix this in order for it to say the correct letter grade based on each percentage?

My code:

```
    /*Write a program to read 3 grades. Grades are between 0-100. Calculate the average, then print the 
    following message. */
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void main() {
    int grade1{};
    int grade2{};
    int grade3{};
    int average{};
    int sum{};

    cout << "Enter 3 grades (as a number between 0-100): " << endl;
    cin >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3;

    sum = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3);
    average = (sum / 3);

    if (grade1+grade2+grade3/3 <= 100)
    {
        cout << "Your average is: " << average << "," << " your letter grade is A." << endl;
    }
    else if (grade1+grade2+grade3/3 <= 89)
    {
        cout << "Your average is: " << average << "," << " your letter grade is B." << endl;
    }
    else if (grade1+grade2+grade3/3 <= 79)
    {
        cout << "Your average is: " << average << "," << " your letter grade is C." << endl;
    }
    else if (grade1+grade2+grade3/3 <= 69)
    {
        cout << "Your average is: " << average << "," << " your letter grade is D." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Your average is: " << average << "," << " your letter grade is F." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `cin >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3;` doesn't check for (and then correct) errors. The user can generate wrong results with a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

`grade1+grade2+grade3/3` is wrong. Division is calculated before addition in C++, so only `grade3` is divided by 3 while `grade1` and `grade2` are not divided.

You have already calculated `average`, so you should use that instead of the wrong formulas.

Also the condition looks wrong. It seems you should use `>=` or `>` (according to the specification) instead of `<=`.

Comment: that and testing `<= 100` as a first step :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey Ah, thank you.

Comment: Should I then replace each of the (grade1+grade2+grade3/3) with average?

Comment: @NithinRajesh Yes.

Comment: Now I did it but it's outputting A every time I have a average less than or equal to 89, so how do I make it say the letter grade is B?

Comment: @NithinRajesh look at what your first `if` statement says.  **Every** average that's 100 or lower gets the A.  If the average is `0`, that satisfies your `average <= 100` condition.

Comment: It works now, thank you all for your help! Have a nice rest of your day! :)